# Running .bat file in zsh (in Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, zsh

On a Windows machine I want to avoid using `cmd.exe` at all cost. I'm trying to use babun (mintty 1.1.3) to run a batch file in a Windows folder.

This works:

```
{ ~ } » ./file.bat -o /path/to/files.xml
```

However, I would like to do something like:

```
{ ~ } » cd /path/to/  
{ ~ } » ./"c:\Program Files\App\file.bat" -o files.xml
```

However, all I get is `zsh: no such file or directory:`

I have tried `sh`, `cmd /c` and some other commands I've found, to no avail. I have also tried using a more linux-friendly path format, i.e. `c:/Program\ Files/App/file.bat`

I will be grateful for any help with this.

Comment: Are you sure UAC virtualization isn’t playing tricks on you and the file actually elsewhere? Because Linostar’s answer definitely works.

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm not sure. How can I check that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try removing the dot-slash `./` from the beginning of the path? A `.` means the current directory, and putting it before an absolute path, like the one you are using, usually makes no sense.

Try:

```
{ ~ } » "c:\Program Files\App\file.bat" -o files.xml
```

or

```
{ ~ } » "c:/Program Files/App/file.bat" -o files.xml
```

**UPDATE:**

or try using:
`"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/App/file.bat" -o files.xml`

Comment: Thanks, Linostar. Yes, that's the first thing I tried. The result is the message "zsh: command not found: C:\Program Files\App\file.bat" (for your former suggestion) or "The system cannot find the specified path" (for the latter).

Comment: What is the output of the **pwd** command in your zsh? That will give a good idea how your absolute paths should be written.

Comment: Since it’s basically Cygwin on steroids, it can work with Windows paths, mostly. `"G:/test.bat"` works for me, including a correctly set working directory and whatnot.

Comment: Thanks, @Linostar: The output of **pwd** is `/cygdrive/c/Users/Manuel/SkyDrive/path/to/files.xml`.

Comment: I have tried putting a simpler `test.bat` (with no -o arguments) which just prints `Hello World` in the same folder where `file.bat` is, and that one works. So weird.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your pwd's output.

Comment: I have tried again and the two options with the forward slashes work, both of them. Thanks a lot!